# Flatten and De-flatten for Solr input/output

Tags: java, parsing, solr

I have lots of Java objects which have parent child relationships.

These need to be put into Solr.

To do that, we convert the Java object into json as follows:

```
{
  "employee": {
    "name" : "John",
    "address": {
      "apt": 100,
      "city": "New York",
      "country": "USA"
    },
    "vehicles": [
      {
        "name" : "Hyundai",
        "color" : "red"
      },
      {
        "name" : "Toyota",
        "color" : "black"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now since Solr does not handle this, I am flattening it out as follows:

```
"employee.name": "John",
"employee.address.apt": 100,
"employee.address.city": "New York",
"employee.address.country": "USA",
"employee.vehicles_0.name": "Hyundai",  // Note how arrays are being flattened
"employee.vehicles_0.color": "red",
"employee.vehicles_1.name": "Toyota",
"employee.vehicles_1.color": "black",
```

It is easy to flatten, but clients of my library do not want the flattened schema when they query.

So I need to de-flatten the above on return from Solr and convert them back to the original Java object.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

I am thinking of somewhat crude way of taking the flattened output from Solr (as shown above) and write a parser to put the fields back to Java objects. But this seems like lot of work. An easy way out or an existing tool would be much appreciated.

I am using Solr 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Solr is designed for search, not storing deep object graphs. You might be better off optimizing the Solr records for search and then getting the original objects from the master store by recordID or some such.

Think about what will you be trying to find. For example, will you be searching for individual vehicles? If yes, your current document level should be a vehicle not an employee.

Comment: Even if I try to search for say just employees by name, there should be some way to retrieve full employee info.

Comment: I would also like to get all employees having red car.
Or all employees driving Toyota etc.
Also note that this is a very simple example.
There are hundreds of entities in reality which we want to store and retrieve and the level of hierarchy in those entities can be 5 to 10 levels.

Comment: Solr will definitely **not** help you store entities 10-level deep. You need to think through your search strategy first. What will you search and what you will want to find. You may discover that you want multiple entities types, maybe even separate collections with the same data repeated in various shapes. Then, you get your original entities from the relational database.

Answer (score 0):

You can index your documents in a Parent->Child structure at first place.

Take a look at this blog post: http://blog.griddynamics.com/2013/09/solr-block-join-support.html